# send automated voice call in react native

Tags: react-native

I am developing an app that can go through an array of phone numbers and call one by one. And when the user answers the call, an automated voice should be played. Can anyone please help me by giving some suggestions to develop this app. Please mention any useful packages that I can use for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done only React Native. You have to use third party API. As there will be so many calls so it will be better to put that in backend. Here are some API you can use :-

1. [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/)
2. [Exotel](https://exotel.com)
3. [Tropo](https://www.tropo.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. These are not open source it seems..can you please share any open source api's if you have any idea.